# create windows user using Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi

I need to create new windows user as administrator using Delphi

Thanks

Comment: or a command line utility that can do that

thanks

Comment: solved using net user but if there is any other solution plz post

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use the [NetUserAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370649%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [NetUserSetGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370658%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions declarated in the [JEDI Headers](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/apilibrary.html).

see this simple sample.

```
program ProjectAddNewUser;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  JclWin32,//Jedi Library
  Windows,
  SysUtils;


function CreateWinUser(const wServer, wUsername, wPassword, wGroup:WideString): Boolean;
var
  Buf       : USER_INFO_2;//Buf for the new user info
  Err       : NET_API_STATUS;
  ParmErr   : DWORD;
  GrpUsrInfo: USER_INFO_0;//Buf for the group
  wDummyStr : WideString;
begin
  wDummyStr:='';
  FillChar (Buf, SizeOf(USER_INFO_2), 0);
  with Buf do
  begin
    usri2_name      := PWideChar(wUsername);
    usri2_full_name := PWideChar(wUsername);//You can add a more descriptive name here
    usri2_password  := PWideChar(wPassword);
    usri2_comment   := PWideChar(wDummyStr);
    usri2_priv      := USER_PRIV_USER;
    usri2_flags     := UF_SCRIPT OR UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD;
    usri2_script_path := PWideChar(wDummyStr);
    usri2_home_dir    := PWideChar(wDummyStr);
    usri2_acct_expires:= TIMEQ_FOREVER;
  end;

  GrpUsrInfo.usri0_name:=PWideChar(wGroup);

  Err := NetUserAdd(PWideChar(wServer), 1, @Buf, @ParmErr);
  Result := (Err = NERR_SUCCESS);

  if Result then //NOw you must set the group for the new user
  begin
  Err := NetUserSetGroups(PWideChar(wServer),PWideChar(wGroup),0,@GrpUsrInfo,1);
  Result := (Err = NERR_SUCCESS);
  end;
end;

begin

  if CreateWinUser('localhost', 'MyNewUser','ThePassword','MyWindowsGroup') then
   Writeln('Ok')
  else
   Writeln('False');

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: @RRUZ: i'm trying this code, but it fails on NetUserSetGroups with error 2220 (The group name could not be found). I'm trying to create a user with the "Adminitrators" group.

Comment: To make it work with the local `Administrators` group, I had to change three lines of code.  `GrpUserInfo: USER_INFO_0` became `LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_3`.  `GrpUserInfo.usri0_name:=PWideChar(wGroup)` became `GrpUsrInfo.lgrmi3_domainandname := PWideChar(wUsername)`.  And `Err := NetUserSetGroups(PWideChar(wServer),PWideChar(wGroup),0,@GrpUsrInfo,1)` became `Err := NetLocalGroupAddMembers(PWideChar(wServer), PWideChar(wGroup), 3, @GrpUsrInfo, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the API call you need is [NetUserAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370649%28VS.85%29.aspx).

First, check if Delphi provides a wrapper for this call. If not, you'll have to write your own. If you don't know how to make Windows API calls from Delphi, you have some more research to do.

Comment: +1, I couldn't find it. I've got a feeling Delphi can call these functions directly, assuming they match the correct calling convention... like you I don't know.