# NetUserAdd and expires date

Tags: windows, delphi, user-controls

Am trying to create a windows user using delphi.

Like the answer in this post: [create windows user using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444541/create-windows-user-using-delphi/2445264#2445264).

I tried to change the usri2_acct_expires to a specifyed date but the user is created with a (never) option.

I've set the value like this:

```
usri2_acct_expires  := DateTimeToUnix(datetimepicker1.date);
```

Thanks for help.